# Rest template in Spring always returns null in response

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rest, resttemplate

```
@Service
public class NewsServiceImpl implements NewsService {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("NewsApi")
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    private static final String API_KEY="91979e2003354739930fcf50472d3ea";
    private static final String BASE_URL = "https://60bbf97e3a39900017b2e1d5.mockapi.io/api/v2";

    @Override
    public List<News> getAllNews() {

        MultiValueMap<String,String> uriVariable = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();


        String uri = buildURI(BASE_URL+"/everything",uriVariable);
        System.out.println(uri);
        String responseEntity = this.restTemplate.getForObject(uri, String.class);
        System.out.println(responseEntity);
        return null;

    }

    private String buildURI(String url, MultiValueMap<String, String> params) {

       return UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(url)
               .queryParams(params)
                .toUriString();
    }


}
```

The URL built is correct as I am able to click on it from log. But the response is null.
I tried adding response handler but there also its null

Comment: Your method returns `null`. Maybe it is the case

Comment: Compare it with the output you are getting from tools like Postman or SOAP UI. It may give you hint

Comment: I get the response properly from the postman. I even tried by logging URL in log and clicking it

Comment: were you able to figure it out? having same issue